# Autowiring Spring Authentication Manager in Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've set a custom authentication provider:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("samlAuthenticationProvider")
    SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /**
         * Do your stuff here
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider);
    }   

}
```

Now, I'd like to set also an alias for the authentication-manager, then I'd like to autowire it in another bean definition.

Eg:

```
<!-- Register authentication manager with SAML provider -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="samlAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
<bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler" />
</bean>
```

Is there a way to do that only in Java Config?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not well with new Security Java Configuration, but here is what I see from source code:

```
@Import(AuthenticationConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableGlobalAuthentication {}
```

This annotation imports `AuthenticationConfiguration` who is `@Configuration` as well. Any `@Configuration` is registered as bean, too. So, you can do like this from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Autowired
public void setAuthenticationConfiguration(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) {
     this.authenticationConfiguration = authenticationConfiguration;
}
```

And get access to the `AuthenticationManager`:

```
this.authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
```

From xml perspective you can use SpEL to get access to that `authenticationManager`:

```
<property name="authenticationManager" value="#{authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager}" />
```

Sorry, I don't see the point, where `AuthenticationManager` is registered as a bean. From here you can't configure an **alias** for him.

**UPDATE**

BTW, if you are going to `@Autowired` the `AuthenticationManager` to some other component, the `@Value` come to the resque:

```
@Value("#{authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager}")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

**UPDATE2**

Found it `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. The source code and JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Override this method to expose the {@link AuthenticationManager} from
 * {@link #configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)} to be exposed as
 * a Bean. For example:
 *
 * <pre>
 * &#064;Bean(name name="myAuthenticationManager")
 * &#064;Override
 * public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
 *     return super.authenticationManagerBean();
 * }
 * </pre>
 *
 * @return the {@link AuthenticationManager}
 * @throws Exception
 */
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return new AuthenticationManagerDelegator(authenticationBuilder);
}
```

**UPDATE3**

How tou get access to the existing `AuthenticationManager` from custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`and configure `SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter`?

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlFilter() {
    SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
    samlFilter.setAuthenticationManage(authenticationManager());
    .......
    return samlFilter;
  }

  @Override  
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.addFilter(samlFilter());
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. I'd like completely avoid to use XML: is there a way?

Comment: Added a `@Value` injection sample

Comment: Right, of course. It is exactly the result of that JavaDoc

Comment: How about do this from that method: `return this.authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();` ? However from here there is need to see your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation

Comment: I've a NullPointerException

Comment: As I said: you should show your code to investigate

Comment: The code is above. I defined a SecurityConfig class, then I'd like to use the configured AuthenticationManager into another configuration class by autowiring it.

Comment: Good. Since you are going there to configure `SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter` I'd suggest to use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` there, too. And overrride `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. And so on

Comment: Ok, but then how can I pass the AutheticationManager as method param in a new bean definition?

Comment: From here you should show that bean definition and point out where you have a confuse

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't clear for me. Could you show me a simple code-sample?

Comment: Added sample for `Filter` configuration

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class UsernamePasswordAuth extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    public UsernamePasswordAuth(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/services/login");
    }
}
```